# How to use counsel-git-grep without using back slash

Tags: counsel

I am using [`counsel-git-grep`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) to grep for a string in the current Git repository.

Lets assume I am searching string " `[ok]` ". In order to obtain correct results I have to provide input as " `\[ok\]` " ; where `\` should be added before some characters like `[`, `]`, `"`, etc.

Is there any way achieve the `grep` results without using `\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in theory this should be possible by adding `-F` to the grep flags in the `counsel-git-grep-cmd-default` variable by evaluating

```
(setq counsel-git-grep-cmd-default "git --no-pager grep -F -n --no-color -I -e \"%s\"")
```

(of course you could add this to your init.el file)

However, I am not sure if it works in practice (because of some weird behaviors I am not able to test it here quickly).

Comment: This ignores the white spaces tho like `hello world` couldn't be search. For a single space, I had to do double space -- is this behavior normal?

Comment: According to [this section](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#ivy--regex-plus) of the Ivy manual, this is indeed normal behavior